# ffmpeg returns error cur_dts is invalid when converting mp3 to ogg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, ogg

need some help with this part of code:

```
ffmpeg -y -fflags +igndts -i "/var/radio-content/temp/music/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3" -map 0:0 -filter:a "loudnorm,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,volume=5dB"  -vsync 2 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k -q:a 5  "/var/radio-content/songs/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3.ogg";
```

i'm trying to convert mp3 to ogg. after execution the ogg file is created in destination folder, but it is only about 3-4 KB. as i understand this is not the permission issue, because i ran it also as a root user.

debug output is too big and for some reason i cannot paste it here, therefore i will only paste the part which contains error message. what can be wrong with above command? i've used it several time in other productions with similar server configuration and installed software. didn't find any appropriate solution in the internet.
any thoughts? DEBUG:

````
Input #0, mp3, from '/var/radio-content/temp/music/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Мегахит (Vitalik Solt Remix) (Sefon.me)
    artist          : Burito
  Duration: 00:03:28.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 50, 1/14112000: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url /var/radio-content/songs/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3.ogg.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0:0.
Applying option filter:a (set stream filtergraph) with argument loudnorm,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detectio                                                                                                                                                                           n=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,volume=5dB.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument libvorbis.
Applying option b:a (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 128k.
Applying option q:a (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) with argument 5.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /var/radio-content/songs/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3.ogg.
[file @ 0xcd6b80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
detected 2 logical cores
[Parsed_silenceremove_1 @ 0xce9fe0] Setting 'start_periods' to value '1'
[Parsed_silenceremove_1 @ 0xce9fe0] Setting 'start_duration' to value '1'
[Parsed_silenceremove_1 @ 0xce9fe0] Setting 'start_threshold' to value '-60dB'
[Parsed_silenceremove_1 @ 0xce9fe0] Setting 'detection' to value 'peak'
[Parsed_aformat_2 @ 0xceb100] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'dblp'
[Parsed_silenceremove_4 @ 0xceae40] Setting 'start_periods' to value '1'
[Parsed_silenceremove_4 @ 0xceae40] Setting 'start_duration' to value '1'
[Parsed_silenceremove_4 @ 0xceae40] Setting 'start_threshold' to value '-60dB'
[Parsed_silenceremove_4 @ 0xceae40] Setting 'detection' to value 'peak'
[Parsed_aformat_5 @ 0xced3c0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'dblp'
[Parsed_volume_7 @ 0xced720] Setting 'volume' to value '5dB'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0xd052c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0xd052c0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0xd052c0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's16p'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0xd052c0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0xd052c0] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:s16p samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 0xcecb40] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 0xcd4b80] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_0' between the filter 'graph_0_in_0_0' and the filter 'Parsed_loudnorm_0'
[Parsed_aformat_2 @ 0xceb100] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_1' between the filter 'Parsed_silenceremove_1' and the filter 'Parsed_aformat_2'
[Parsed_silenceremove_4 @ 0xceae40] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_2' between the filter 'Parsed_areverse_3' and the filter 'Parsed_silenceremove_4'
[Parsed_aformat_5 @ 0xced3c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_3' between the filter 'Parsed_silenceremove_4' and the filter 'Parsed_aformat_5'
[Parsed_volume_7 @ 0xced720] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_4' between the filter 'Parsed_areverse_6' and the filter 'Parsed_volume_7'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xce7c00] query_formats: 11 queried, 15 merged, 15 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0xd08260] [SWR @ 0xd086c0] Using fltp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0xd08260] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16p r:44100Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dbl r:192000Hz
[auto_resampler_1 @ 0xd06a80] [SWR @ 0xd1d660] Using dblp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_1 @ 0xd06a80] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dbl r:192000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dblp r:192000Hz
[auto_resampler_2 @ 0xd060a0] [SWR @ 0xd32600] Using dblp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_2 @ 0xd060a0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dblp r:192000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dbl r:192000Hz
[auto_resampler_3 @ 0xced0a0] [SWR @ 0xd475a0] Using dblp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_3 @ 0xced0a0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dbl r:192000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dblp r:192000Hz
[auto_resampler_4 @ 0xd5c780] [SWR @ 0xd5cc60] Using dblp internally between filters
[auto_resampler_4 @ 0xd5c780] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:dblp r:192000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:192000Hz
[auto_resampler_4 @ 0xd5c780] tb:0.000005 sample_rate:192000.000000 nb_channels:2.000000
[Parsed_volume_7 @ 0xced720] n:nan t:nan pts:nan precision:float volume:1.778279 volume_dB:5.000000
Output #0, ogg, to '/var/radio-content/songs/85e45890-cdca-4754-aabf-295ce01dbf45.mp3.ogg':
  Metadata:
    title           : Мегахит (Vitalik Solt Remix) (Sefon.me)
    artist          : Burito
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/192000: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 192000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libvorbis
      title           : Мегахит (Vitalik Solt Remix) (Sefon.me)
      artist          : Burito
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 348 times
Killedst message repeated 110 times```
````